# MySQL Tree Structure Database - The best way to copy a node?

Tags: mysql, tree

I have a database with 3 columns (node_id, node_parent, title). Right now, I'm trying to figure out the best way to copy a node and keep the parent id.

Here's what I mean:

[image]

I'm thinking about doing it recursively with PHP and run through each node and child but it seems to me that it's not optimized at all. Is it possible to do this just with MySQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

If you like to add a new row keeping the `node_parent` and `title` from a existing row using one single query, this should work:

```
INSERT INTO <table> SELECT NULL, node_parent, title FROM <table> WHERE id = 1;
```

Note that the `node_id` column should be set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: I should have written 'duplicate' instead of 'copy'. I want to keep the node_parent only for the node I want to copy. Every other child below that node, should have the parent_id of the node just copied. I'm wondering if I can do this only with mysql.

Answer (score 0):

How many levels do you need to copy? If just one, then you can do the following:

```
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT NULL,node_parent, title FROM table1 WHERE id=2;
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT null,LAST_INSERT_ID(),title FROM table1 where node_parent=2;
```

As previous poster mentioned, node_id should be AUTO_INCREMENT.